# Every prime number has multiple of form $100\dots01$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does Every Prime number (except $2,3,5$) has a multiple of form $10^k+1$ where $k\in N$?

I check till $29$ and it seems to be true. However it got gigantic. $29\times3448275862069=10^{14}+1$

I Proved using pigeonhole that every prime (except $2,5$) has multiple of form $10^k-1$ but am not able to do it with $10^k+1$

Comment: Perhaps consider performing long division on $100 \dots 01$

Comment: Try $p=43{{}}$.

Comment: @H.PWiz That's gonna be reaaaaaly inefficient

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I left my pc running about 5 minutes for 31 (with no avail). Unless you're talking about doing it mathematically, I dont think my pc can handle that

Comment: Or $p=37{}{}{}$.

Comment: Computational note:  testing a number like $31$ is easy.  You only have to test up to exponent $30$ and if you work $\pmod {31}$ throughout then each test is extremely fast.

Comment: My method is really inefficient tbh. I was just checking if $(10^{k}+1)/p$ is integer iterating over k

Comment: @AFalseName [doesn't seem inefficient to me](https://tio.run/##LYxBDoIwFAX3PcVbVv0aP5gQTHoET0CI6aKERgql1Ljx7rUlvtUsZt6ot5eZppQGOHiBL4JxBaEU/Jmh0K3vJUK6Ex/g@6IscTThYzeDfQq7UaI7Bki@Hv8nORDCaTtnx2n/eEL6YOeIS/byXdcQM3FNnKGlqqaqpVvTp/QD)

Comment: @H.PWiz all that Haskell Wizardry... Incomprehensable to just a mathematica/python pleb

Comment: Still just long division

Comment: A curious note: this happens iff the decimal expansion of $1/p$ can be divided into two parts that sum $999\cdots9$. For instance, $1/7=0.142857$ and $142+857=999$.

Comment: The key point for testing a prime is that you only have to check up to $p-1$.  To see that, note that [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) tells us that $10^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ so, for instance, $10^{37}\equiv 10^7\times 10^{30}\equiv 10^7 \pmod {31}$.

Comment: So my "conjecture" is not true. Does anyone see any patters for the primes which can be expressed as $(10^k+1)/m$

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A028416

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$10^3-1=999=27\times 37.$$
So $10^3\equiv1\pmod {37}$. Modulo $37$ the powers of ten are $1,10,26,1,10,26,1,\ldots$. None of these are $\equiv-1\pmod{37}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note:   $10^k\equiv -1 \pmod p\implies$ the order of $10\pmod p$ is even (if $L$ is the least exponent such that $10^L\equiv -1\pmod p$ then the order of $10\pmod p$ is $2L$).

The order of $10\pmod {31}$ is $15$ which is odd, so the claim fails in that case.

Comment: what does "The Order of 10" mean here?

Comment: It means the least non-zero $n$ such that $10^n\equiv 1 \pmod p$

Comment: Is it not possible that order be lesser than $k$?

Comment: Yes, I misspoke, though the conclusion is correct.  Since $10^k\equiv -1$ we can let $L$ be the least exponent such that $10^L\equiv -1$ and then the order is $2L$.  I will edit.